# Parse - Push - Receiving pushes from previous installation

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've two diferent apps in Parse (dev and prod app) for the same android application.
When some device is registered in one app, let's say the dev app. The device receives correctly the pushes sended from that Parse app.
But when the same device installs the production version of the android app (which has the keys for the production Parse app), the device continues receiving the pushes sended from the Parse development app (I insist, the keys are diferent, we have this double checked).
It's like there is some kind of cache or persistent asociation between the device and the first registered Parse app.

Do I have some way of clear, reset, delete or restart the device for Parse?

Comment: Ensure both apps 'dev' and 'production' do not have the same apple certificates and parse push notification certificates

Comment: In iOS both apps have different certificates and also there are of different types (development and production accordingly).
In the case of Android neither of both has "GCM Push Credentials". Is this what you're asking?

Comment: I am running into this same issue, and am actually in the middle of trying to resolve. Did you ever find the answer to this? I do have some ideas. I believe that you need to unsubscribe the user to the channels you are using when logging out the user. The issue seems to be with ParseInstallation. You may need to also look into using ParseUser.logout().

Comment: The issue is at the registration of the device in the Parse app. I have not found the solution for this. It seems like when the installation object is created for one app, remains linked forever.
I have implemented in addition one channel for dev and another for prod. So when the app is started checks the environment and sets the correct channel. So later when we send the pushes we filter the targets with this channel.
Is not pretty, but works for now. The another workaround is to remove the installation object from Parse (through rest or the web platform).